# Java scanner nextInt(16) does not accept negative hex values

Tags: java, int, hex

I need to read in a 32-bit number in hex format. When I enter a negative value, I get an input mismatch exception. Everything works as long as the number is positive (00000000 ~ 7FFFFFFF), but anything negative (80000000 ~ FFFFFFFF) fails.

```
     System.out.println("Enter first number in hexadecimal format: ");
     Scanner readX = new Scanner(System.in);
     int a = readX.nextInt(16);
```

I have tried various formats (FFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, -FFFFFFFF, -7FFFFFFFF, ~FFFFFFFF) with the same results.

Any ideas? I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I'm completely stumped!

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried `-1` ?

Comment: Try `-A`... you'll get `-10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will fail for the same reason `2147483648` (one more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) will fail for `Integer.parseInt`: The value is too large.  It will not interpret `ffffffff` or `80000000` as a negative number, but as a large positive number.  Those numbers are simply too large to be interpreted as an `int`.

[`Scanner.nextInt(int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)) matches a regular expression to see if it could be an `int`, then it passes it to `Integer.parseInt` for parsing:

> If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Integer.parseInt with the specified radix.

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) will throw a `NumberFormatException` if it can't be represented as an `int`:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

You must specify the number to be negative.  Try `-1` or `-80000000` or anything in between; they will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Enter first number in hexadecimal format: ");
 Scanner readX = new Scanner(System.in);
 String a = readX.nextLine().trim();
```

int result =  Integer.parseInt(a, 16);
This will be work for youThen you get value as scientific notation if it's not fit to int.